# Access Combobox items through invoke (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am invoking a method of a usercontrol in my form, but the Combobox in the usercontrol does not contain any items in the invoked method. When i run the same method without using invoke (i.e. put a button directly in the usercontrol and run the same method), the combobox has the items. Code below.

code in Form1:

```
        Type type = ActiveModelControl.GetType();
        var control = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("RunSimulation");

        object[] param = new object[] { modelinfo };

        var results = method.Invoke(control, param);
```

code in usersontrol:

```
    public List<double> RunSimulation(IModel model)
        {
           [other code]   

           List<string> tempSecurityList =

    GetSecurityList(SecurityListComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());

               [other code]  

        }
```

Comment: You invoke the method on a new unshown usercontrol. Why do you expect that something is selected on the unshown Usercontrol.

Comment: I don't know why i did not realize what i was doing wrong, but this was an easy fix. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Using Activator.CreateInstance() is dead wrong.  You created a completely new ComboBox object, of course it is empty.  You have to dig out the one that the user is looking at.